# First query auth fails with Nuxt Apollo

Tags: graphql, session-cookies, apollo-client, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt/Apollo to connect to a headless wordpress with WPGraphQl using cookie as authentication.

The problem I have is that when I start npm run dev, run build or incognito mode the first page load always fails but when I reload the page again it works without problem.

I have checked that in the error page (first load) the cookie is already created, but apparently the query for some reason is sent without said authentication.

https://prnt.sc/nM4lEoUBoFow

How can I solve this problem?

Nuxt: 3.6.5
@NuxtJS/Apollo: 5.0.0-alpha.6

./components/../nav-component.vue

```
<script setup>
const query = gql`
  query NavigationMenu($id: ID!, $size: MediaItemSizeEnum = MEDIUM, $include: [MediaItemSizeEnum] = MEDIUM) {
    menu(id: $id, idType: DATABASE_ID) {
      count
      menuItems(first: 15) {
        nodes {
          order
          label
          uri
          connectedNode {
            node {
              databaseId
              isTermNode
              ... on Category {
                name
                posts(first: 5) {
                  nodes {
                    uri
                    title
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const variables = { id: 727 }

const { data: { value: { menu } } } = await useLazyAsyncQuery({
  query,
  variables,
  key: 'main-navigation',
  cache: true,
})

const menuItems = menu.menuItems.nodes;

</script>

<template>
  <nav aria-label="primary">
    <ul class="nav-primary">
      <NavItem
        v-for="{uri, label, connectedNode: { node}} in menuItems"
        :link="uri"
        :label="label"
        :key="label"
        :data="node"
      />
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>
```

*./nuxt.config.ts*

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiUser: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_USER || '',
      apiPass: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_PASS || '',
    }
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
  ],
  apollo: {
    authType: 'Basic',
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'https://example.com/graphql',
        tokenName:'lpder',
      }
    },
  },
})
```

*./plugins/apollo.ts*

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

  const config = useRuntimeConfig();

  const cookie = useCookie('lpder')
  nuxtApp.hook('apollo:auth', ({ client, token }) => {
    const tokenized =  btoa(`${config.public.apiUser}:${config.public.apiPass}`) ;

    cookie.value = tokenized;
  })
})
```